# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'session_id' in 'field list'

Tags: magento-enterprise, mysql, sql, magento-1.4

How can I solve this kind of error after transferring my magento file and SQL to new hosting?

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'session_id' in 'field list'

Please see this screenshot for the error: [image: http://prntscr.com/3yj69u]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522061/sqlstate42s22-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-session-id-in-field-li

Comment: Hi Amit,

I got this error

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'rmmagsde_database.report_viewed_product_index' doesn't exist

This is the screenshot1: http://prntscr.com/3ykmg2

And when I got login I see this error also.

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'rmmagsde_database.sales_flat_order' doesn't exist

This is the screenshot2: http://prntscr.com/3ykmug

Comment: Have you cleared, the cache? Are you using the same version of Magento on the new hosting company? Did you wait for the SQL script to finish importing?

Comment: Hi Brent,

Yes! I cleared all the cache from var/cache folder, I am still using the same version of magento, and yes finish and wait the SQL script importing successful..

Comment: But still I get the error.. Please help! Anybody?

Comment: Where are you storing your sessions?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that something has gone wrong when coping over your databases. Maybe it did not complete or something.

The error suggests that the column `session_id` is not on the table `log_visitor`. Which it should be, at least in version 1.6 and upwards.

I would suggest that you try again with your database copy. Make sure that it completes and validate the old database and new database to see if there are any issues between the two regards structure of the log_visitor table.